# Errors after update to PHP 7.4: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on array

Tags: php, wordpress

After I updated the PHP Version of our WordPredd website to PHP 7.4 I get an error when using a plugin.

The Error:

```
Ein Fehler vom Typ E_ERROR wurde in der Zeile 39 der Datei /homepages/12/d38950651/htdocs/clickandbuilds/SKYLIGHTVeranstaltungstechnikGmbH/wp-content/plugins/musexpress/includes/converter/utils/class-muse-converter.php verursacht. Fehlermeldung: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on array in /homepages/12/d38950651/htdocs/clickandbuilds/SKYLIGHTVeranstaltungstechnikGmbH/wp-content/plugins/musexpress/includes/converter/utils/class-muse-converter.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/12/d38950651/htdocs/clickandbuilds/SKYLIGHTVeranstaltungstechnikGmbH/wp-content/plugins/musexpress/includes/converter/class-pages-converter.php(190): MusexPress\Converter\Utils\Muse_Converter::convert_redirect_elements(Object(simple_html_dom), 'mietpark')
#1 /homepages/12/d38950651/htdocs/clickandbuilds/SKYLIGHTVeranstaltungstechnikGmbH/wp-content/plugins/musexpress/includes/converter/class-pages-converter.php(124): MusexPress\Converter\Pages_Converter->page_conversion('https://www.sky...', '/homepages/12/d...', Array, 'desktop')
#2 /homepages/12/d38950651/htdocs/clickandbuilds/SKYLIGHTVeranstaltungstechnikGmbH/wp-content/plugins/musexpress/includes/converter/class-conversion-handler.php(60): MusexPress\Converter\Pages_Converter->init()
#3 /homepages/12/d38950651
```

and this is the PHP snippet:

```
static function convert_redirect_elements( $page_parse, $page_name ) {
    foreach ( $page_parse->find( 'link[rel="canonical"]' ) as $element ) {
        $element->href = Php_Converter::get_permalink( $page_name );
    }
    foreach ( $page_parse->find( 'link[rel="alternate"]' ) as $element ) {

        if ( strpos( $element->href, 'phone/' ) !== false ) {
            $element->href = Php_Converter::get_permalink( "phone-" . $page_name );
        } else if ( strpos( $element->href, 'tablet/' ) !== false ) {
            $element->href = Php_Converter::get_permalink( "tablet-" . $page_name );
        }
    }
    // error happens on the below line
    foreach ( $page_parse->find( 'head', 0 )->find( 'script' ) as $element ) {
        $element->innertext = str_replace( 'phone/' . $page_name . '.html', Php_Converter::get_permalink( "phone-" . $page_name ), $element->innertext );
        $element->innertext = str_replace( '../' . Php_Converter::get_permalink( "phone-" . $page_name ), Php_Converter::get_permalink( "phone-" . $page_name ), $element->innertext );
        $element->innertext = str_replace( 'tablet/' . $page_name . '.html', Php_Converter::get_permalink( "tablet-" . $page_name ), $element->innertext );
    }
}
```

Line 39 is:

```
foreach ( $page_parse->find( 'head', 0 )->find( 'script' ) as $element ) {
```

Comment: @AD7six could the return value of the method `find` of the object `$page_parse`. OP uses `$page_parse->find()->find()` and didn't get this error in the previous `foreach ($page_parse->find() as ...)`

Comment: @AD7six well, I'm not sure in fact. `find( string $selector [, int $index] )` *"Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an array of object."* OP used *index* and `find` should have returned a single object, not an array

Comment: I'll never figure out why it's **so hard** to look at the trouble-place via `print_r()` or via `var_damp()`... for example, check `$page_parse->find( 'head', 0 )` and then add and check `->find( 'script' )`...

Comment: plugin have no support . you may deactive plugin with rename folder 
wp-content/plugins/musexpress

Comment: @AD7six this is what `$page_parse` is defining: `//gets html entities from a string
$page_parse = str_get_html( $page, true, true, DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, false, DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT );`

Comment: So! I've got it! I had to replace the simple_html_dom.php in the plugins root with the latest version and the errors go away. I have much to lern. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @jnshrst please answer your own question (edit the question to focus on the actual problem) and accept the answer.